# Why does this dark mode code made with Jquery works?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was trying to find a way to make a dark / light mode with jquery.
And I came up with this

The thing I don't understand is when I remove the 'darkmode' class, it should add 'whitemode' class, but instead it adds only the attribute (class) without the actual class. Yet It works perfectly. Why is that?

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="darkmode.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/aa7be85309.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <title>Dark Mode</title>
</head>
<body class='whitemode'>

<div class="darkmode"></div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Light / Dark mode</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui non numquam excepturi corrupti vel dicta commodi veritatis eaque eius harum blanditiis voluptatem dolores itaque iure ex, molestias expedita rem velit?
    </div>

    <div class="toggle-btn" id='toggle-btn'><i class="fa-regular fa-moon"></i></div>


    <script src="main.js"></script>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**darkmode.css**

```
body{
    transition-duration: .3s;
}
.container{
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.toggle-btn{
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#toggle-btn{
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

body.whitemode{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}

body.darkmode{
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}

.border{
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle-btn").click(function(){

        if($("body").hasClass('whitemode') ? ($("body").toggleClass('whitemode'), $("body").toggleClass("darkmode"), $("#toggle-btn").toggleClass("border")) : ($("body").toggleClass("darkmode"), $("#toggle-btn").toggleClass("border")));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because `background-color: #fff; color: black;` are the default styles for the body element in the vendor stylesheet.